# solve symmetric second covariant derivative

Tags: partial-derivative

I am trying to find either

- a general solution
- a non-trivial class of solutions

to the following equation:

\begin{equation}
(D_i D_j + D_j D_i) 1 = s_{ij}
\end{equation}

where $D_i = \partial_i - a_i$ is a derivative (I think), $s_{ij}$ is an arbitrary symmetric tensor, and 1 is just the real number. (By solution, I mean I am ideally looking for $a$ in terms of $s$.) If it helps, the answer can be valid only in 3 dimensions.

Comment: Your notation $_{(i}D_{j)}$ isn't standard, at least for me.. Could you expand a little what you mean by that.

Comment: @JeanMarie That is not what the notation says, it says $D_i$ and $D_j$ separately. Edit, sorry it seems like it has just been edited :)